# AttributeError: module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'Field' not fixed with torchtext.legacy

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to use torchtext.data.Field() from torchtext but it is not working in any way I have tried.

I have tried with
`from torchtext.legacy import data` but it does not seem to work. I have also tried to install another version of torchtext (currently have 0.16.2) by running `pip install torchtext==0.10.0` but I get this error message in the terminal

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchtext==0.10.0 (from versions: 0.1.1, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.3, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.16.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchtext==0.10.0
```

Has anyone experienced this error before?

I am using a conda environment with Python version 3.12.1 and my torch version is 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`torchtext` is supported till `python 3.11`

**https://pypi.org/project/torchtext/**

You need to downgrade to `python 3.11` or install `python 3.11` separately to work with `torchtext`

[image]

Comment: I actually downgraded Python to 3.8.0 and installed pytorch 1.11.0 and then installed torchtext and now it works. Thanks for the idea!